# instance variable and methods are not allowed in call to super constructors

Tags: java, constructor

Why are instance variable and methods not allowed in call to super constructors or the call to overloaded constructors?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is it possible to do computation before super() in the constructor?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2303604/is-it-possible-to-do-computation-before-super-in-the-constructor)

Answer (score 1):

Because when you call the super constructor, it's to build parent class. Due to class hierarchies, your child class is not yet constructed when building parent class. let's illustrate with an example

```
class Parent() {
    protected String s;
    public Parent(String s) {
        System.out.println("parent created with "+s);
        this.s = s; // don't do this at home, kids, one letter variables stinks like hell
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    public Child(String s) {
        // don't try to put an instruction here, it's impossible due to the mandatory call to super as first instruction
        super(s);
        System.out.println("child created with "+s);
    }
}
```

When you call `new Child("I'm the king of the world")`, the first method called is in fact `Parent(String)`, as System.out will show up. And that's quite normal, because as `Child` is a subclass of `Parent`, the underlying `Parent` object must be created before the `Child` object is.

What does this has to do with instance variables ? Well, they exist only when object is created. As a consequence, instance variables of `Child` are not available while creating a `Parent` object. In the following example

```
class OtherChild extends Parent {
    private String prefix = "some ";
    public OtherChild(String s) {
        // don't try to put an instruction here, it's impossible due to the mandatory call to super as first instruction
        super(prefix+s);
        System.out.println("child created with "+s);
    }
}
```

You'll have an initialization error because the `prefix` field is not initialized when calling suoper constructor, as the Child object in fact does not yet exists at this precise time. Was my explanation clear enough ?

Comment: so when these variables(prefix) are initialized..immediately after the supclass constructor ..is this right

Comment: Yes, the instance initializers get called after the super ctor and just before the actual ctor.

Comment: No, instance initializer are the variable assignments in the instance variable declarations (if any), and any code in `{ ... }` outside of methods or constructors (but not `static { ... }`, this is a static initializer).

Answer (score 0):

Because the object is not initialized completely. The object can be in the inconsistent state which is error prone and hard to discover. Static methods can be called because they are independent of the object state.

Answer (score 0):

Because at the time the super is getting called, instance variables don't exist yet! Wherever there is a `new` statement to create an object of that class in the heap, its constructor first would call `super()` -by default- or your `super(..)` -in case you specify one- and then would continue by initializing the object's fields.