# Java constructors

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [About Constructors in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371369/about-constructors-in-java)

Can a constructor in java throw exceptions?

What all things we need to keep in mind about this when it comes to inheritance?

Can anybody please elaborate on this topic or provide some links which can be helpful?

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Class/Payingattentiontoexceptionsinconstructors.htm