# Does the Java ClassLoader load inner classes?

Tags: java, classloader

If I have a inner class declaration such as:

```
Class A {
    public static class B {
    }
}
```

followed by:

```
Class<?> implClass = getClass().getClassLoader().loadClass("A");
```

Will the A$B inner class be loaded as well?
What if the B inner class was not declared as "static" ?

Comment: Any code in a static initializer block will run when the class is loaded, so this should be pretty easy to test.

Comment: http://ideone.com/dalGQ6

Comment: Also, don't confuse loading with initializing (resolving) a class.

Comment: A class is loaded when it is needed, or when you ask for it.  This doesn't change because a class is nested.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Once the code is compiled, *there's no such thing as an inner class*. If you look at the results of `javac`, you'll see two files:

```
A.class
A$B.class
```

So class `B` is not loaded when `A` is loaded, `B` just *happens* to be defined in `A`.

---

#### Edit

For example, given these two files,

```
package kuporific;

public class A {
    private static class B {}
    private class C {}
}
```

and a `build.gradle` file (for convenience):

```
apply plugin: 'java'
```

First, build by running `gradle build`. Then, unzip the resulting JAR file (located in `build/libs`):

```
├── META-INF
│   └── MANIFEST.MF
└── kuporific
    ├── A$B.class
    ├── A$C.class
    └── A.class
```

Opening each file (in IntelliJ, for example), reveals what the compiler has done:

- `A.class`:

  ```
  package kuporific;

  public class A {
      public A() {
      }

      private class C {
          public C() {
          }
      }

      private static class B {
          public B() {
          }
      }
  }
  ```
- `A$B.class`:

  ```
  package kuporific;

  class A$B {
      private A$B() {
      }
  }
  ```
- `A$C.class`:

  ```
  package kuporific;

  import kuporific.A;

  class A$C {
      private A$C(A this$0) {
          this.this$0 = this$0;
      }
  }
  ```

Notice that

1. `A$B` does not have a reference to its parent, `A`, while `A$C` does. This is because the former is a static inner class, and the latter is not, and
2. both `A$B` and `A$C` are now *package private* classes.

This is how non-static inner classes are able to directly reference their parent instance's fields and methods, and vice versa. (Any private fields of the parent class referenced in an inner class are made package private as well.)

Next, let's see what effect loading class `A` has on `A$B` and `A$C`.

First, add the following Java class:

```
package kuporific;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException {
        Main.class.getClassLoader().loadClass("kuporific.A");
    }
}
```

Now add the following to the `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'application'
mainClassName = 'kuporific.Main'
applicationDefaultJvmArgs = ["-verbose:class"]
```

The `-verbose:class` outputs all classes that are loaded by the JVM (see [Java - Get a list of all Classes loaded in the JVM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2548384/java-get-a-list-of-all-classes-loaded-in-the-jvm)).

Run `gradle run` on the command line (which runs the `main` method of `Main`); the output (with my added notes) is

```
:compileJava
:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:run
[Opened /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Object from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar]
# Lots of omitted output...
[Loaded kuporific.Main from file:/tmp/build/classes/main/]
        ^ here!
[Loaded sun.launcher.LauncherHelper$FXHelper from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Class$MethodArray from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded kuporific.A from file:/tmp/build/classes/main/]
        ^ here!
[Loaded java.lang.Shutdown from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar]
[Loaded java.lang.Shutdown$Lock from /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_20.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar]

BUILD SUCCESSFUL

Total time: 6.502 secs
```

We can see when `kuporific.Main` and `kuporific.A` were loaded, and we do not see either `kuporific.A$B` or `kuporific.A$C` being loaded.

Comment: Not exactly. `A.class` still retains information that `A$B` is an inner class of `A`. You can access this information via reflection.

Comment: @ghik True enough, but loading class `A` will not load the inner  class `B`, static or not. I have edited my answer to better explain this.

Comment: @ghik The compiler performs some subtle magic to make the semantics of inner classes work (which is part of your "not exactly".)

Comment: But calling getEnclosingClass() A$B will nevertheless load A. So this information must be somewhere. Is it in the name?

Comment: Could you please also provide official documentation for the same if any?

Answer (score 3):

Inner classes i.e `class B` cannot exist outside the parent class. You need to construct the parent class i.e `class A` first.

and if you remove static from your inner class i.e for **non-static inner class** , you need to pass the parent class in during construction of the inner class.

```
Object a = Class.forName("A").newInstance();    //object of outer class

//object of inner class
Object b = implClass.getDeclaredConstructor(new Class[] { a.getClass() })
        .newInstance(new Object[] { a });
```

Comment: I don't think that is true for **static** inner classes

Comment: @ dkatzel  This solution is mainly for non static inner classes and he question is for bolth `satic inner classes` and `nonstatic inner classes`

Comment: OK I see that now, if you make your answer more clear that the code is for non-static only. I will remove down vote.  (maybe add reflection call for how to call static inner class ?)

Answer (score 2):

A `ClassLoader` will not load a class, unless it was requested (e.g. using `loadClass`). While loading a class, a `ClassLoader` will request referenced classes.

As your class `A` does not reference `A.B`, `A.B` will not be loaded, whether it is static or not. (To be honest, `A` does reference `A.B`, but not in a manner causing the `ClassLoader` to load `A.B`.)

If you add a field of type `A.B` or use the type `A.B` in another way (e.g. as a method return type), it will actually be referenced in `A.class` and therefore be loaded.

Comment: Don't confuse loading with initializing (resolving) a class. `ClassLoader#loadClass(String)` does not initialize a class.

Answer (score 2):

The code below is runnable and can illustrate some of the other answers:

```
public class Outer
{

   private static final String TEST01 = "I'm TEST01";

   static
   {
        System.out.println("1 - Initializing class Outer, where TEST01 = " + TEST01);
   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
       System.out.println("2 - TEST01       --> " + TEST01 );
       System.out.println("3 - Inner.class  --> " + Inner.class);
       System.out.println("5 - Inner.info() --> " + Inner.info() );
   }

   private static class Inner
   {

       static
       {
          System.out.println("4 - Initializing class Inner");
       }

       public static String info()
       {
           return "I'm a method in Inner";
       }
    }
}
```

Please, pay attention to the sequence numbers, especially in this line:

```
System.out.println("5 - Inner.info() --> " + Inner.info() );
```

When you run the program you will see the following result on the console:

```
1 - Initializing class Outer, where TEST01 = I'm TEST01
2 - TEST01       --> I'm TEST01
3 - Inner.class  --> class com.javasd.designpatterns.tests.Outer$Inner
4 - Initializing class Inner
5 - Inner.info() --> I'm a method in Inner
```

A little more detail for each step:

1 - 'Outer' is initialized when you Run the program. The static variable TEST01 is initalized before static block. Inner is not initialized.

2 - The 'main' method is called and shows the value of 'TEST01'; then,

3 - The System.out shows reference to 'Inner'. **Inner is not initialized**, but it was loaded (that's why it has reference in the memory model).

4 - Here's the most interesting part. Because the System.out needs to access the 'info()' method in 'Inner' ( Inner.info() ), the 'Inner' class should be initialized **before** returning the result of the 'info()' method. That's why this is the step 4.

5 - Finally, the System.out has all data it needs to show, and then the last line is showed on the console.

So, as it was well pointed by @sotirios-delimanolis ( [Does the Java ClassLoader load inner classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24538509/does-the-java-classloader-load-inner-classes#comment37999635_24538703) ) loading a class is different from initializing it.

Answer (score 0):

No, the nested class will not be loaded, in either case.