# Is this singleton pattern thread safe?

Tags: java, thread-safety, singleton

I have a singleton server instance and I'm curious whether my code is thread safe. [I've read](http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html) about different singleton patterns, and I think the way to go generally is the `double-checked locking` pattern, which goes as follows:

```
public static Singleton getInstance() {
    if(singleton == null) {
        synchronized(Singleton.class) {
            if(singleton == null) {
                singleton = new Singleton();
            }
        }
    }
    return singleton;
}
```

This is supposedly an efficient thread-safe way of setting/getting a singleton. The easiest way to get  and set a singleton, I've read, is `lazy instantiation`, which looks like this:

```
public static ClassicSingleton getInstance() {
    if(instance == null) {
        instance = new ClassicSingleton();
     }
     return instance;
}
```

Now what I want to know is if my variation is thread-safe. My code:

```
public static void startServer(int listeningPortNumber) throws IOException {
    if (server != null) {
        throw new IOException("Connection exists");
    }

    server = new Server(listeningPortNumber);
}
```

My code is very similar to the *lazy instantiation* pattern above, but I can't see how my code isn't thread-safe. Is there something I'm not seeing or is this actually valid code?

---

Reference: http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073352/core-java/simply-singleton.html

Comment: WHAT DO YOU WANT TO DO THAT YOU NEED IT THREAD SAFE ?

Comment: @StackFlowed That's irrelevant

Comment: @StackFlowed WHY ARE YOU **SHOUTING**?

Comment: @Pshemo caps got pressed by mistake

Comment: @OlaviMustanoja Was curious ...

Comment: @StackFlowed I see. Well, I think I don't really need it to be, I'm just curious and wanted to educate myself.

Comment: This question seems relevant: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5307003/java-multi-threading-atomic-reference-assignment

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not safe.

Imagine what happens if two threads call `startServer` at the same time (or close enough to it):

1. Thread A checks `server != null`, and sees that `server` is null -- so it doesn't throw an exception
2. Thread B does the same
3. Thread A now instantiates `new Server(listeningPortNumber);`
4. Thread B does the same, and presumably bad things happen at this second instantiation

If `server` isn't `volatile`, the problem is even worse, since you don't even need the interleaving anymore -- it's possible that Thread A instantiates the `new Server(...)`, but that the write to the `server` field isn't seen by Thread B for a long time (possibly forever) because it's not flushed to main memory.

But the method is racy even if `server` is `volatile`, because of the interleaving.

Answer (score 3):

No, lazy singleton pattern is not thread safe.

If you want a thread-safe version of the Singleton pattern in Java, you should implement Bill Pugh's solution. The code is here:

```
public class OptimalSingleton
{
  protected OptimalSingleton()
  {
    // ...
  }

  private static class SingletonHolder
  {
    private final static OptimalSingleton INSTANCE = new OptimalSingleton();
  }

  public static OptimalSingleton getInstance()
  {
    return SingletonHolder.INSTANCE;
  }
}
```

More about it on SO: [Singleton pattern (Bill Pugh's solution)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6109896/singleton-pattern-bill-pughs-solution)

Comment: I wasn't asking whether or not lazy instantiation is thread-safe. I know it isn't. How about my variation? If it's not, can you explain why.

Comment: Probably yeah. But more expensive the lock, the double checking, etc. than Bill Pugh's solution. So why do you want to invent a new way, which (probably) worse than the existing solutions. And no one knows, so no one will be able to understand you code easily.

Comment: I have no interest in a proved pattern. I'm simply curious.

Comment: I would say, that yeah, it's thread safe. But the idea behind your solution is the same if the `getInstance()` would be `synchronized`. Except your solution would be slower, 'cause the double `if`.

Answer (score 3):

Your code is not thread safe.

Suppose you have two threads, A and B that call `startServer(...)`, and that prior to these calls the server has not been initialized. A passes one value (a) and B passes another (b) to the method. The only thing you know is that within each thread the order of operations is defined.

So the following is possible:

```
A: check server != null  (false)
B: check server != null  (false)
A: server = new Server(a)
B: server = new Server(b)
```

Clearly this violates the singleton. Thread A will see a server that's initialized to a value different to the one passed in, and an exception was never thrown.

Answer (score 1):

Your code isn't thread safe!
Suppose 2 different threads simultaneously call startServer method
Both see the server variable is null so will skip the if block
And each thread creating an instance of Server! So you will end with 2 instance of a server in your application.