# What happens when a constructor partially succeeds before throwing an exception?

Tags: java, exception, constructor

Suppose I have the following base class:

```
public class RootClass {

  private List<RootClass> children = new ArrayList<RootClass>();

  public RootClass(RootClass parent) {
    if (parent != null) {
      parent.addChild(this);
    }
  }

  public void addChild(RootClass child) {
    children.add(child);
  }

}
```

And I have the following child class:

```
public class ChildClass extends RootClass {
  public ChildClass(RootClass parent) {
    super(parent);
    doInitialization();
  }

  private void doInitialization() {
    //Might throw an unchecked exception
  }
}
```

Now, suppose I create an instance of a `ChildClass` that throws the exception, but is caught outside the constructor (somewhere in the depths of the code, so far away, it doesn't know that the `ChildClass` has not been fully constructed). Now the parent has a reference in its `children` list to the `ChildClass` which has not had its constructor run.

How should these situations be handled?  Is this just a bad design scheme?  Or does this make the least bit of sense?  I don't really want to refactor the entire application to add the child to the parent after the constructor finishes.

Comment: possible duplicate of [About Constructors in Java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371369/about-constructors-in-java)

Comment: what's the meaning of "possible" duplicate?

Comment: This kind of questions need more votes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a general principle, leaking the value of 'this' out of constructors is to be avoided at all costs. In this case the parent object will have a reference to a half-constructed object. It should be coded in the caller as e.g. parent.addChild(new Child()) rather than have the add be automatic.

Comment: I was wondering if there's a valid usage of this pattern. Or rather, is there a reason why java allows compiling this kind of code?

Comment: @Pacerier the compiler isn't there to prevent you writing unsafe code, only to prevent you from writing +incorrect+ code.

Comment: well if there's no a valid use case for that kind of code, it might as well have been considered as "incorrect"

Comment: @Pacerier Nobody said there wasn't a valid use case. And you're still confusing the functions of the compiler and the language specification.

Comment: no I was confused about what could be a valid use case for leaking `this` pointer before constructor ends

Comment: @Pacerier It is possible to be confused about more than one thing at a time :-|

Answer (score 1):

If this:

```
 private List<RootClass> children = new ArrayList<RootClass>();
```

Was a static field, you would just have leaked a half-initialized object into the wild. As it is not, it just won't make any difference.

You only have an issue if this reference leaks to somewhere out of the object, then you would have a half-initialized object waiting to cause issues on your system. As long as you make sure the reference does not go anywhere out of itself, it's all good.

Comment: No, he leaked it, cause the parent, that is a legitimate and already existing instance, now has a reference to the children.