# Is it possible to create my own primitive datatype in java. like int, float,double

Tags: java, types, type-conversion

How to create my own datatype in java,  that will accept value range from 0 to 1024.

My declaration would be.

```
kilobyte a=10;
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Short answer: no. Long answer: nope.

Comment: In Java you'd typically make a Kilobyte Class for stuff like this.

Comment: Java has BigInteger. Take a look at that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot create your own primitive, but you could have a wrapper `Object` for that.

Dirty example here:

```
// note that class name doesn't follow Java conventions here
public class kilobyte {
    private int number;

    public kilobyte(Number number) {
        if (number == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("argument is null");
        }
        else if (number.intValue() > 1024 || number.intValue() < 0) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("argument not within 0 < x < 1024 range");
        }
        else {
            this.number = number.intValue();
        }
    }
    // TODO getter/setter
}
```

Comment: Personally, I'd probably have allowed `0` as a valid value.  What's with accepting a `Number`, as opposed to using an int?  For that matter, extending `Number` is potentially a viable option.  Oh, and throwing an exception in a constructor [can get messy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371369/can-constructors-throw-exceptions-in-java); in this sort of situation, it'd be better to use a static constructor anyways - especially with a _heavily_ input-constrained type, caching immutable objects is likely to show dividends here.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse your comment contains all kinds of valid observations (+1 on my side). Note that my post says "dirty example" for a reason :)

Answer (score 4):

No. Java doesn't allow that (i.e. creating a primitive). But you could create your own class for that.

Answer (score 1):

No, you cant create your own primitive type neither overload the operators, so this is not possible in java.